# Autostart with KDE Device Notifier

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, kde

I want to automatically start a program when a new device is connected. I can create an action in the Device Notifier that I can click to start as soon as the new device is connected, but is there a way to make the Device Notifier call an action after the corresponding device has been mounted?

Answer (score 1):

I think the keywords you have to search for are "udev rules", because udev handles stuff like that.